# Não retornar valor de um campo, quando este for zero

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou criando uma consulta em `SQL`, porém preciso que determinado campo não exiba os valores quando este for zero.

É possível?

```
SELECT gfilial.nomefantasia AS 'Filial',
       tmov.codtmv AS 'CODTMOV',
       tmov.numeromov AS 'Número',
       tmov.valorliquido AS 'Valor líquido',
       tmov.valorbrutoorig AS 'Valor bruto',
       titmmov.nseqitmmov AS 'ITEM',
       titmmov.idprd AS 'IDPRODUTO',
       tproduto.codigoprd AS 'Cód. produto',
       tproduto.nomefantasia AS 'Produto',
       titmmov.codund AS 'Unidade',
       titmmov.precounitario,
       titmmov.quantidade,
       titmmov.valorbrutoitem
  FROM tmov WITH(nolock)
```

Comment: Henrique, é possível sim, mas poderia ser mais especifico, colocando o seu SQL, e destacando os campos que você deseja que não sejam exibidos?

Comment: Não quer que exiba o campo da linha? Ou nem quer que exiba a linha? Reitero o que o @jmfrolim pediu para ser mais específico. Exemplos ajudariam bastante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE t.valor
         WHEN 0 THEN NULL
         ELSE t.valor
       END AS valor
  FROM tabela t
```

> [`CASE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189074(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> A expressão CASE é usada para avaliar várias condições e retornar um valor único para cada condição.

Comment: Nesse caso vou ter que informar uma condição (Case WHEN) para cada campo da consulta? Sou iniciante em SQL. Paciência comigo galera.

Comment: @HenriqueBonfim acho que seria interessante você colocar um exemplo do resultado que busca obter na sua pergunta, senão vai ficar difícil de entender o que você quis dizer

Comment: exemplo: produto capa de chuva | quantidade 0,00   quando a quanitdade (titmmov.quantidade) for 0, eu gostaria que não surgisse o valor. Deu pra entender?

Comment: @HenriqueBonfim no caso por valor você quer dizer a linha?

Comment: sim.  tentei o "...CASE TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 
TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE END AS QUANTIDADE..." porém retornou o seguinte erro: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @HenriqueBonfim O problema é que você colocou com `'` e isso faz o BD tentar converter o valor.

Comment: Como faria nesse caso, já que pelo que entendi a forma de escrever vazio é  ' '?

Comment: @HenriqueBonfim vazio é `NULL` a menos que você queria retornar uma `string` vazia

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal. Consegui dessa forma "CASE TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE WHEN '0.0000' THEN NULL ELSE TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE END AS 'Quantidade'"... mais os recursos do RM Totvs para não mostrar nulos, o resultado foi o correto.

Answer (score 3):

Sim isso é possível atráves do comando IF

Assim :

```
SELECT IF(MEDIA_SALARIO = 0 , '', MEDIA_SALARIO) FROM FUNCIONARIO WHERE ID_FUNCIONARIO = 1;
```

Também pode customizar os valores quando eles forem null assim :

```
  SELECT IF(MEDIA_SALARIO IS NULL , '', MEDIA_SALARIO) FROM FUNCIONARIO WHERE ID_FUNCIONARIO = 1;
```

Exemplo besta okay? Só para entender o funcionamento.

```
SELECT GFILIAL.NOMEFANTASIA AS 'Filial', TMOV.CODTMV AS 'CODTMOV', 
TMOV.NUMEROMOV AS 'Número', TMOV.VALORLIQUIDO AS 'Valor líquido', 
TMOV.VALORBRUTOORIG AS 'Valor bruto', TITMMOV.NSEQITMMOV AS 'ITEM', 
TITMMOV.IDPRD AS 'IDPRODUTO', TPRODUTO.CODIGOPRD AS 'Cód. produto', 
TPRODUTO.NOMEFANTASIA AS 'Produto', TITMMOV.CODUND AS 'Unidade', 
TITMMOV.PRECOUNITARIO ,CASE TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE 
TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE END AS QUANTIDADE, TITMMOV.VALORBRUTOITEM FROM TMOV 
WITH(NOLOCK)

tente isso e vê se vai!
```

Leia também :

> [COMANDO CASE](https://www.portaleducacao.com.br/conteudo/artigos/educacao/utilizando-a-clausula-case-em-um-select-sql-server/6356)

Comment: Não existe comando `IF` no `SQL Server`

Comment: Aonde ele especificou ser SQL SERVER?

Comment: Nas `tags` da pergunta: `sql` `sql-server`

Comment: Nesse caso vou pontuar sua resposta! Mas a pergunta se refere também a linguagem SQL e não só a quem a implementa!

Comment: Foi mal se não ficou claro que se trata do SQL Server. Mas realmente não consegui com a sentença explicada pelo colega

Comment: Não sei se ajuda mas, preciso que o campo TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE, retorne em branco, quando o valor for zero.

Comment: A querie do @sorack  está corretissíma! Pode alterar sua pergunta e postar o querie lá em cima!

Comment: segue consulta realizada     "SELECT GFILIAL.NOMEFANTASIA AS 'Filial', TMOV.CODTMV AS 'CODTMOV', TMOV.NUMEROMOV AS 'Número', TMOV.VALORLIQUIDO AS 'Valor líquido', TMOV.VALORBRUTOORIG AS 'Valor bruto', TITMMOV.NSEQITMMOV AS 'ITEM', TITMMOV.IDPRD AS 'IDPRODUTO', TPRODUTO.CODIGOPRD AS 'Cód. produto',
  TPRODUTO.NOMEFANTASIA AS 'Produto', TITMMOV.CODUND AS 'Unidade', TITMMOV.PRECOUNITARIO ,TITMMOV.QUANTIDADE, TITMMOV.VALORBRUTOITEM 
FROM TMOV WITH(NOLOCK)"

Answer (score 2):

Tente utilizar o `CASE` para o campo em questão, caso esteja utilizando o SQLSERVER.

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE_TEMP (ID INT , VALOR NUMERIC(15,2))
INSERT INTO #TABLE_TEMP (ID, VALOR)
VALUES(1,11.00),(2,8.54),(3,NULL),(4,0.00)

SELECT * FROM #TABLE_TEMP
SELECT ID, CASE WHEN VALOR = 0.00 THEN NULL ELSE VALOR END FROM #TABLE_TEMP
```

Tem outras formas, mas creio que essa já te auxilie por ser mais simples.